# how to stop fetching all records when term is % or _ (underscore) in sql?

Tags: sql

I have one Company table, here company name can contain any special character or alphanumeric value. 
When I am searching from company table where name contains % or _ (underscore), It's giving all the records from the table because of the default behavior of % or _ in SQL.

My query is as follows:

```
declare term nvarchar(100) = %
Select * from tblUSer where name like '%'+term+'%'
```

Expected result: I should get only the records where company name contains % or _.

Comment: You are using `like` - do you mean `=` ?

Comment: try `.... where name like '%' + replace(term, '%', '[%]') + '%'
`

Comment: Yes, I am using like operator.

Comment: The term for this is "escaping" the characters. That's the term for pretty much all languages, not just SQL.

Comment: What is you database server? Mysql?

Comment: @PascalFares  I am using SQL DB

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks i didn't knew about dat

Comment: @Curiousdev Well, I just looked it up, and it turns out I'm wrong. Default there is no escape, but you can define one with the `escape`-clause. However your use of a character group `[%]` doesn't work in all database systems (it works for SQL Server).

Comment: There are several SQL engines. Which are you using? MySql, Microsoft SQL Server, postgres, Oracle,...? Whichever it is, you should search how to escape wildcards in its syntax.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel i completely agree wid u :)

Comment: Please edit your tags to state exactly which database system you're using, so someone can post a relevant answer. Stating "I am using sql DB" is not enough; all DB use SQL. Give a name like oracle, Postgres, sql-server etc. Commments are not for answering

Comment: Your Welcome Happy Coding @bhanwarrathore :)

Comment: @Curiousdev, Thanks for the help.                                                       
 select top 5 * from tblClient Where ClientName  like '%' + replace(@term, '%', '[%]') + '%'    . This is working for me

Comment: That's cool but you should use `WHERE name LIKE '%abc\%%' escape '\'` as per @MarkRotteveel said in previous discussions it's more reliable

Comment: @Curiousdev, how can we do the same search with _ (underscore) instead of %

Comment: @bhanwarrathore same way  `LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: @Curiousdev I completely agree to the solution.  You can refer this link for more information on escaping wild card characters.
http://www.techtamasha.com/escape-single-quotes-and-wild-cards-_-in-ms-sql/20

Comment: That's nice @ABDCHAMP thanks for sharing :) bhanwar rathore please look into this url it'll help you

Comment: @ABDCHAMP  . I have gone through this doc. Thanks for the help.